# NUMA simulation on x86_64 machine

Tags: multiprocessing, simulation, numa

I wanted to know if there is a way to perform experiments specific to NUMA architecture
on a x86_64 machine, by some sort of simulation tools.

I cam across some resource on creating fake NUMA nodes but couldn't figure out how exactly
to use them. Virtual machines are also fine, if there is a way.

Thanks,